# Task Scheduler running a bat file that duplicates screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

When you lock a computer on windows 7 your login screen appears on your main display and then on other monitors it is completely black, when your displays are extended. This problem is fixed when you duplicate displays, because when you lock your computer that picture and login screen appears on both. I want that for more or less a better look to my computer. I know this is technically not needed but I liked the idea. So I created a batch file that is called DuplicateOnLock. All it says is this:

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

This bat file works if I just run it myself. So I set it up in Task Scheduler that when I lock my computer it triggers a run of this command. I do know the path is right because if I run it manually (the task) it will run and duplicate my displays. I also gave the task the highest admin capabilities. I also have another command that when I unlock the computer it Extends my screen. Also that bat file says is:

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /extend
```

Once again this runs fine. Has all the same settings as the one above except it runs on unlock and this is not running as well. I believe this is not working because the computer is locked and the command is not working because my computer is simply locked and on the desktop and windows just discards it. I think would be a very neat trick if I could get it to work. If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening and can help me come up with an idea I would great appreciate it.

I did try delaying the command as well to see if that fixed the issue. Sadly that did not.

Comment: The Task scheduler environment may not be the same as your `cmd` prompt. Try using the full path.

Comment: Possibly related: [Running `mode` from the Windows 8.1 Task Scheduler](http://superuser.com/q/883878/354511), in which a Task Scheduler task triggered by lock/unlock/standby/resume cannot configure the display. I wonder whether it has something to do with the Task Scheduler task running under a different Session ID than the active, interactive session.